# ASP.NET URL REWRITING- Parameter is not single word

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using URLREWRITER.NET DLL for URL Rewrite in my project.

What I've achieved so far :

The URL `http://localhost:8080/Movie.aspx?MovieName=Titanic`

has been successfully rewritten to `http://localhost:8080/movie/titanic.aspx`

but when the Parameter has value with multiple words, its not getting redirected.

Eg. The URL `http://localhost:8080/Movie.aspx?MovieName=The+Interview`

it should become `http://localhost:8080/movie/the_interview.aspx`

Below is the Web.Config Code :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter"
             requirePermission="false"
             type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
  </configSections>

  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule" />
    </modules>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  </system.webServer>

  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/movie/(.+).aspx" to="~/Movie.aspx?MovieName=$1" />
  </rewriter>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Show your code... Without code the solution can be as simple as a string replace. But then you would not have this question.

Comment: @peer : I've added the Web.config code above